# Short Integer Solution Problem with ||z||<=B

Tags: lattice-crypto

Why following constraints on $||z||$ are required

$||z||<=B, B<q$

[image]

Comment: The Short Integer Solution problem is trivial for $\beta = q$, as the scaled basis vectors $q\vec{e}_i$ satisfy:
$$f_{\mathbf{A}}(q\vec{e}_i) = \mathbf{A}q\vec{e}_i \equiv 0\bmod q$$

Comment: Thank you your answer but What about ||z||<=B ?